# How to using JQuery toggle class for the next element, not all at once

Tags: jquery

I've written some jQuery to change visibility of some elements but the visibility for all of the elements is changed at once. I only want apply the change to the next element. I tried to use `.next()` but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<span class="close_button">x <div class="comment_report">Click!</div></span><br>
<span class="close_button">x <div class="comment_report">Click!</div></span><br>
```

CSS:

```
.comment_report{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.visible{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close_button").click(function() {
        $(".comment_report").toggleClass("visible");
    });
});
```

Here's my demo http://jsfiddle.net/6hahA/

Comment: Note: in HTML, you cannot put a `div` into a `span`. Please rethink your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `<div>` with the class `.comment-report` is a child, all you have to do is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close_button").click(function() {            
        $(this).find(".comment_report")
            .toggleClass("visible");
    });
});
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/6hahA/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)(). Since the div is a child of the span.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".close_button").click(function() 
    {
        $(this).children(".comment_report").toggleClass("visible");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leetaylor/6hahA/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find` or `.children` to select the matching element:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".close_button").click(function() {
            $(this).find('.comment_report').toggleClass("visible");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lee is correct - Change line 3 to...

```
        $(this).children(".comment_report").toggleClass("visible");
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6hahA/5/